# Python RegExp global flag

Tags: python, regex, global, flags

Is there a flag or some special key in python to use pattern multiple times.
I used to test http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ my RegExp, it worked correctly in it.
But when testing in correct enviorment match only returns *None*.

```py
import re
pattern = r"(?P<date>--\d\d-\w+:\d\d)[ \t]+(?P<user>\w+)[ \t]+(?P<method>[\w ]+)[\" ]*    (?P<file>[\w\\:\.]+)@@(?P<version>[\w\\]+)[\" ]*(?P<labels>[\(\w, \.\)]+){0,1}[\s \"]*(?P<comment>[\w \.-]+){0,1}[\"]"
base = """
--02-21T11:22  user3   create version "W:\foo\bar\fooz.bat@@\main\1" (label1, label2,   label3, label22, label33, ...)

"merge in new bat-based fooz installer"

--02-21T11:22  user1   create version "W:\foo\bar\fooz.bat@@\main\0"

--02-21T11:22  user2   create branch "W:\foo\bar\fooz.bat@@\main\"

"merge in new bat-based fooz installer"

--02-13T11:22  user1   create version     "W:\foo\bar\fooz.bat@@\main\1"

  "Made to use new fooz.bat"

"""
r = re.match(pattern, base)
print(r)
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`re.match` tries to match the pattern at the start of the string.
You are looking for `re.search`, `re.findall` or `re.finditer`

Answer (score 20):

Each of the Python regular expression matching functions are useful for different purposes.

`re.match` always starts at the beginning of the string.

`re.search` steps  through the string from the start looking for the first match. It stops when it finds a match.

`re.findall` returns a list of all the search matches.

In all the cases above, if there's a group in the regex pattern, then the item you get back is a tuple of the full match followed by each group match in the order they appear in the regex pattern.