# Regex in Django template tag matches only once

Tags: python, regex, django, django-templates

I have a template tag like this:

```
@register.filter(name='bknz')
def bknz(text):
    pattern = re.compile(r"(?P<start>.*)\(bkz: (?P<bkz>.*)\)(?P<end>.*)")
    link = r'\g<start>(bkz: <a href="/baslik/\g<bkz>"  title="%\g<bkz> search Twitter">\g<bkz></a>)\g<end>'
    text = pattern.sub(link,text)
    return mark_safe(text)
```

It changes the (bkz: something) to linked (bkz: something). It works fine but only once. When I put a few (bkz: sth) to my object. It only renders the last one in object as changed version. How can I run this as much as necessary? Thanks.

Comment: There's probably a `g` flag for `global` searches. So instead of returning on the first match, it will continue searching the entire string

Comment: Maybe try [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686516/python-regexp-global-flag)

Comment: Not worked. Any other ideas from anyone?

Comment: How are you using this filter in your view?

Comment: I don't use it in views. It's in templatetags directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked.

```
@register.filter(name='bknz')
def bknz(text):
    pattern = re.compile(r"(?P<start>.*?)\(bkz: (?P<bkz>[^)]*)\)(?P<end>.*?)")
    link = r'\g<start>(bkz: <a href="/baslik/\g<bkz>"  title="\g<bkz>">\g<bkz></a>)\g<end>'
    text = pattern.sub(link, text)
    return mark_safe(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Take out the start and end groups.** They are not needed; you want to match your `(bkz: something)`, not what's around it.

**Use non-greedy matching** A `.*` in a regex will try to match as much as possible at a time. Use `.*?` to avoid clobbering future instances of the pattern.

```python
pattern = re.compile(r"\(bkz: (?P<bkz>.*?)\)")
```