# How can I use re.match to find numbers?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to use python `re` module:

```
import re

res = re.match(r"\d+", 'editUserProfile!input.jspa?userId=2089')
print(res)
```

I got `None` type for res, but if I replace the `match` by `findall`, I can find the `2089`.

Do you know where the problem is ?

Comment: This one was probably already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686516/python-regexp-global-flag

Comment: `match` matches from the beginning of the string. See [search() vs match()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

Comment: Alternatively you can get the `user id` by using `s.split('=')[1]`

Comment: Thanks, this solves my confusion. I'm trying to do regex instead of string manipulation since there is not much chance to practice them during work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using [`match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.match) to search for a substring in a string.

The method `match()` only works for the whole string. If you want to search for a substring inside a string, you should use [`search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.search).

As stated by [khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood) in the comments, you should take a look at: [Search vs Match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

---

**Code:**

```
import re
res = re.search(r"\d+", 'editUserProfile!input.jspa?userId=2089')
print(res.group(0))
```

**Output:**

```
2089
```

---

Alternatively you can use `.split()` to isolate the user id.

**Code:**

```
s = 'editUserProfile!input.jspa?userId=2089'
print(s.split('=')[1])
```

**Output:**

```
2089
```